# Adding new item ( resultcode from another app ) on listview with same buttonclick

Tags: android, android-listview

After integrating barcode scanner natively (Zxing barcode).In my app, Onclick Scan button i need to scan multiple barcodes and add them (resultcode) to list ( using arraylist)in my app, but second time i click on scan button ( call intent of Zxing app ) arraylist gets clear, so its overriding resultcode on listview.
Here is the code below .

```
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        //retrieve result of scanning - instantiate ZXing object
     IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,intent);

        if (scanningResult != null) {

            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
                    barcode_content.setText(scanContent);
            barcodes.add(scanContent);
                            barcode_list.setAdapter(new adapter());
                        ((BaseAdapter)barcode_list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First its not required to add adapter every time you come in to onactivityResult. Add the adapter in oncreate and than only notify the adapter that is how it goes.

Your list is going blank because you are adding a new adapter every time you complete your scan. Make your adapter public and just call adapter.notifydatasetchange() after you change the list data.

In one line remove this setadapter here in OnactivityResult and do it in Oncreate() and make that adapter public.

If any confusion feel free to ask.

Comment: Varun , thanks for help, just i have done it with Static arryalist.